When answering, is it acceptable to mainly use a trustworthy website or media as proof?
Simply put, can I reference a trustworthy article/news paper/media as the main evidence when answering here? Or is that not enough? More specifically, can a The Guardian article be proof/evidence? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Possible duplicate https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/are-newspapers-considered-to-be-notable-reputable-sources

And no, answering the question you inspired won't cut it for me ;) I'm specifically looking for an aviation source not more news outlets in an echo chamber.

@Jamiec You're damn smart. How'd you know that I was planning on answering your question? As a matter of fact, nobody was able to answer your question as of now. Also, I depleted google searches and I'm pretty sure there's no aviation source reporting the incident. There's simply no such thing, most likely because (at least I assume) it happened in Saudi Arabia. Had it happened in the US, FAA or similar would almost certainly have an incident report/document about the event.

Not all questions can be answered, and there is no point answering "we don't know". The fact is we probably don't and perhaps never will.

The sources you provide in your answer should be more trustworthy than those in the question. A news article may qualify, particularly when it has interviews, but in other cases it may misunderstand sources (e.g., medical questions) or just repeat the unverified claims made by other outlets.
Some questions ask for an even higher level of evidence, which you should meet when possible. On the other hand, sometimes even social media can be used in an answer. For example, I've used Twitter as evidence that a specific person or entity said something, or even when something was posted.
It all depends on the question and the level of quality of the specific article/source.

For the question mentioned in the comments (Did an aircraft have to turn back because a mother left her baby in the terminal?), the Guardian is not a good source because, while they have included their research on other incidents, they do not really provide any evidence about this alleged flight beyond what was already mentioned in other news sources, and in the question itself.
